# Android debugging error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I keep getting this weird error when i try to run my app on my phone: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment` and i don't know why. I think maybe its to do with the way i'm calling fragments? I've alsready searched stack overflow for an answer but all of them seem to relate to maps

---

XML1

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.adrian.desktop.login"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<fragment
android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

XML 2

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.adrian.desktop.ViewProgress$PlaceholderFragment">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Graph"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

java 1

```
package com.example.adrian.desktop;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        TextView loginTXT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logintxt);
        Typeface robotoTHIN = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Fonts/Roboto-Thin.tff");
        loginTXT.setTypeface(robotoTHIN);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

java 2

```
package com.example.adrian.desktop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;

public class ViewProgress extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_progress);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        // init example series data
        GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
                new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
                , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
                , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
                , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
        });

        GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
                this // context
                , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
        );
        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Graph);
        layout.addView(graphView);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_progress, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_progress, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
09-27 18:52:58.122  10725-10725/com.example.adrian.desktop E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.adrian.desktop, PID: 10725
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.adrian.desktop/com.example.adrian.desktop.login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
            at com.example.adrian.desktop.login.onCreate(login.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:350)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:438)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:256)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
            at com.example.adrian.desktop.login.onCreate(login.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Just as a note you should rename you class to Login since all classes should start per convention with an upper case.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace identifies the issue pretty clearly:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
```

You didn't define the Fragment you want to have inflated. Look at examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), the fragment needs a name. For example

```
android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
```

If you don't provide the name, the system has no way of determining what to inflate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the fragment itself (via the name attibute) as you can see in the example from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout):

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Your soution should be this here:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.adrian.desktop.login"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.adrian.desktop.login$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />

</FrameLayout>
```